# Network Analyst not using turns?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, turns

Currently my network analyst is not finding the routes when it comes to taking turns along the network. It is able to find the distance when the two points are along a straight polyline, but when it comes to using a junction to jump to another line, it will come up with an error. I am unsure if it involves a connectivity error or what the deal is.[image]

Comment: Sounds like the network has not been built correctly. Typically edges (lines) connect to each other at junctions (nodes, or end points). You can check this by using the select tool and manually select the lines around the junction. You should be able to select THREE lines.

Comment: Yes thank you. Sorry about the late response. That was exactly it, I had to essentially create a "node" at the junction of all three lines. Thanks again.

Comment: @Hornbydd It looks like you have enough in your comment to write a brief answer.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @hornbydd:

> Sounds like the network has not been built correctly. Typically edges
>   (lines) connect to each other at junctions (nodes, or end points). You
>   can check this by using the select tool and manually select the lines
>   around the junction. You should be able to select THREE lines.